# How to pass multiline text to a command in a parameter?

Tags: linux, command-line

There is a command node `/somejs.js arg1 arg2 arg3`
How to pass multiline text in arg1? T. to.to have:

```
node /somejs.js "Some kind of\nmulti-line\ntext" arg2 arg3
```

When I transmit this, the \n characters appear in the variable in the js script, rather than line breaks.
Thank. (Sorry for my English, I'm using google translator)

Comment: Bash has a `-e` option. You can do things like `echo -e "GET /index.html HTTP 1.1\r\n Host: example.com\r\n..."`. I don't know what Node.js offers, though.

Comment: `echo` has a `-e`.  Bash does too,  but it's a totally different meaning.

Comment: @Daniel - My bad, I meant `echo`. Doh...

Answer (score 4):

In bash you can use `$'...'` expansion to interpret `\n` sequence as a newline.

```
node /somejs.js $'Some kind of\nmulti-line\ntext' arg2 arg3
```

or

```
node /somejs.js "Some kind of"$'\n'"multi-line"$'\n'"text" arg2 arg3
```

Answer (score 1):

A parameter can be enquoted to support newlines:

```
$ echo "hi,
> world"
hi,
world
```

Just in case you think that's some sort of `echo`ism, his python example makes the mechanics really explicit:

```
$ python -c "from sys import argv; print(argv); print(argv[-1])" "multiline
string
works
fine
as
enquoted
parameter"
['-c', 'multiline \nstring\nworks\nfine\nas\nenquoted\nparameter']
multiline
string
works
fine
as
enquoted
parameter
```

Note the python represents newlines in strings with the `\n` too, which is why I went ahead and `print`ed the last parameter as well.